# Get browser's default beforeunload message

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

There are a lot of questions, blog posts etc. to explain how to *customise* the  `beforeunload` message a browser would emit upon navigating away from the page.

It all boils down to the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Place your message here'
}
```

If you'd return an empty string, the browser's default, fully localized, message is returned:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return ''
}
```

I'm wondering if Javascript is able to do the inverse: getting/reading the default localized message. So for example in pseudo-code something like

```
const message = browser.messages.beforeunload

// Chrome EN : message = "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"
// Chrome NL : message = "Ben je zeker dat je deze pagina wilt verlaten?"
// Firefox : message = "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave..."
// ....
```

Comment: There is no standardized way of obtaining that text defined in the spec. If a browser does indeed provide a method for obtaining that text (which I doubt), it won't be available on any other browser. You could keep a list of user agents and their respective unload message. But that's a lot of work and won't include translations (unless you get the users locale and keep track of those too)